# multiple definition of `WinMainCRTStartup and some other functions

Tags: c++, windows, mingw-w64

after I copied folders with libraries and compiler into laptop and set up the project I have got following errors:

```
C:\PCL\3rdParty\VTK\bin\vtkEncodeString-6.0.exe: In function `WinMainCRTStartup':
/home/ruben/mingw-w64/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:154: multiple definition of `WinMainCRTStartup'
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:/home/ruben/mingw-w64/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:154: first defined here
C:\PCL\3rdParty\VTK\bin\vtkEncodeString-6.0.exe: In function `mainCRTStartup':
/home/ruben/mingw-w64/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:182: multiple definition of `mainCRTStartup'
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:/home/ruben/mingw-w64/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:182: first defined here
C:\PCL\3rdParty\VTK\bin\vtkEncodeString-6.0.exe: In function `main':
C:/pcldep/VTK6.0.0/Utilities/EncodeString/vtkEncodeString.cxx:151: multiple definition of `main'
obj\Release\main.o:C:\Users\hostles\Documents\3DF_oprav/main.cpp:28: first defined here
C:\PCL\3rdParty\VTK\bin\vtkEncodeString-6.0.exe:crtexe.c:(.CRT+0x8): multiple definition of `mingw_pcppinit'
```

I spent an hours by searching for solution but wasn´t sucess.

Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong? Thanks.